# How to clear shell values of python?

Tags: python, shell

Assume I am in a python shell. I have entered a=10.

```
>>> a=10
>>> a
10
```

but nothing for c , I mean

```
>>> c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
>>>
```

How can I clear the value of a , so that its should have stored nothing. I mean after clearing if i press a output should similar to c.

Note: Dont want to leave python.

Comment: is it such a bad question  ? Any Explanation please .

Comment: Whoever downvoted you probably did it because if you google "python clear value" the answer is in the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the name with the [`del` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement):

```
del a
```

after which accessing `a` will throw a `NameError` as well:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> a
10
>>> del a
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: very quick , thank you. I need to wait for sometime to accept.